# Javascript "cannot read property of undefined"

Tags: javascript

When running the following code, I am getting the error

> "can't read property 'word' of undefined on the starred.

I'm really stuck as to why so any help would be appreciated!

```
 function MyStim(word,instruction) {
  this.word = word;
  this.instruction = instruction;
}; 

var data = [new MyStim("Cat","Forget"), new MyStim("Dog","Remember"), new MyStim("Sour Patch Kids","Never Forget"), new MyStim("Cookies", "Remember")]

 function getpresent ()  {
     return {
         type: "single-stim",
         **stimulus: "<p style= font-size:100px;text-align:center;padding-top:300px;>"+data[i].word+"</p>",**
         is_html: true,
         timing_stim: 250,
         timing_response: 2000,
         response_ends_trial: false,
     }
 };

for (var i = 0; i<80; i++){  
  timeline.push(getpresent(i));
  i++;
};
```

Comment: Make sure you test each part of your program especially the codes that gets executed first i.e the for loop code. In this case just executing getpresent(0) should have caught it.

Comment: You're also going to get an index out of bounds when your "i" variable goes past the array length. You have 4 objects in your array, and you reference all the way up to 79 in your code...

Comment: you're looping 80 times and have significantly less items

Comment: Don't try to vandalize your post.  You can flag it and ask a moderator to delete it.  They might as this Q&A seems unlikely to help (m)any other users.

Answer (score 3):

`getpresent` doesn't have a reference to the `i` variable that you're expecting it to have.

Change

```
function getpresent ()  {
```

To

```
function getpresent (i)  {
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you haven't defined an argument called `i` to your function:

```
 function getpresent (i)  {
     return {
         type: "single-stim",
         stimulus: "<p style= font-size:100px;text-align:center;padding-top:300px;>"+data[i].word+"</p>",
         is_html: true,
         timing_stim: 250,
         timing_response: 2000,
         response_ends_trial: false,
     }
 };
```

So when you called the function the `i` would have a value. Hence you where trying to read the value of `word` on an `undefined` value.

Furthermore, you have two more errors in your for loop.

- You don't need an `i++` in the body of your loop
- You should loop in the range `[0, data.length)`

The corrected loop is the following:

```
for (var i = 0; i<data.length; i++){  
    timeline.push(getpresent(i));
}
```

Comment: That was a typing error on my part, it still does not work with the argument i.

Comment: @user5826447 You are correct. I didn't checked the `for` statement. Please see my update.

Answer (score 0):

The parameter "i" at your "getpresent" function is missing.

Comment: That was a typing error on my part, it still does not work with the argument i.

Answer (score 0):

After fixing the `function getpresent(i)` issue, I noticed three remaining issues with this code snippet.

This loop -

```
for (var i = 0; i<80; i++){  
  timeline.push(getpresent(i));
  i++;
};
```

The `i++` line inside of the loop block is not necessary. Your IIFE (`(var i = 0; i<80; i++)`) does that for you.

This IIFE also runs a loop longer than the data array's length. So after it gets to the last element in the data array, it catches with "word" is undefined since there are no more objects to iterate over. Changing 80 to `data.length` resolves this. (Alternatively you can test for the existence of data[i] before calling the function).

inside the loop timeline is called. Nowhere else in this codeblock is timeline initialized and is therefore not going to be accessible anywhere outside of this loop. Adding `var timeline = []` resolves this issue (unless you have this set somewhere else).

```
function MyStim(word,instruction) {
  this.word = word;
  this.instruction = instruction;
}; 

var data = [new MyStim("Cat","Forget"), new MyStim("Dog","Remember"), new MyStim("Sour Patch Kids","Never Forget"), new MyStim("Cookies", "Remember")]

 function getpresent (i)  {
     return {
         type: "single-stim",
         stimulus: "<p style= font-size:100px;text-align:center;padding-top:300px;>"+data[i].word+"</p>",
         is_html: true,
         timing_stim: 250,
         timing_response: 2000,
         response_ends_trial: false,
     }
 };

//added initialization
var timeline = []; 

//changed '80' to 'data.length'
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){  
  timeline.push(getpresent(i));
  //removed "i++"
};


console.log(timeline)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should never try and access data that way. Rather pass the data into your function. Don't access your data from outside the scope of the function. Keep your data within scope and relevant to the function that's processing it. Writing code like this is breeding bad habits.

```
<script>
function PresentBuilder()
{
    this.type = "single-stim";
    this.is_html = true;
    this.timing_stim = 250;
    this.timing_response = 2000;
    this.response_ends_trial = false;

    this.set_type = function (type){
       this.type = type;
       return this;
    };

    this.set_is_html = function (is_html){
       this.is_html = is_html;
       return this;
    };

    this.set_timing_stim = function (timing_stim){
       this.timing_stim = timing_stim;
       return this;
    };

    this.set_timing_response = function (timing_response){
       this.timing_response = timing_response;
       return this;
    };

    this.set_response_ends_trial = function (response_ends_trial){
       this.response_ends_trial = response_ends_trial;
       return this;
    };

    this.getpresent = function (data){
        return {
            type: this.type,
            stimulus: "<p style= font-size:100px;text-align:center;padding-top:300px;>"+data.word+"</p>",
            is_html: this.is_html,
            timing_stim: this.timing_stim,
            timing_response: this.timing_response,
            response_ends_trial: this.response_ends_trial,
        } ;
    };
};

function MyStim(word, instruction) {
    this.word = word;
    this.instruction = instruction;
};

var data = [new MyStim("Cat","Forget"), new MyStim("Dog","Remember"), new MyStim("Sour Patch Kids","Never Forget"), new MyStim("Cookies", "Remember")];

timeline = [];
for (var i = 0; i<data.length; i++){  
  timeline.push(new PresentBuilder().set_response_ends_trial(true).getpresent(data[i]));
};

for (var i = 0; i<timeline.length; i++){  
  console.log(timeline[i]);
}
</script>
```

I don't really write javascipt but if I had to, I would rather try it like this. What's important here is how the **data** gets passed to the **getpresent** method.